# Simple logistic regression - calculate likelihood by hand

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, nonlinear-regression

I am following Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis by Montgomery, Peck Vining and on p. 430 they present the likelihood ratio test. It says that

$$
\text{LR} = 2 \left[\ln(L(\text{FM})) - \ln(L(\text{RM})) \right]
$$

The formula then claims that this is equal to:

$$
LR = 2 \left[ \left (\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \ln(\hat{\pi_i}) + \sum_{i=1}^n (n_i -y_i)\ln(1-\hat{\pi}_i) \right)
- \left( y \ln(y) + (n-y)\ln(n-y) - n\ln(n) \right)
\right]
$$

When I calculate the log-likelihood using `logLik` I get different numbers than when I use the formula above. I just don't understand how to calculate the log-likelihood by hand. Here are my workings.

```
# Data
exposure = c(5.8, 15.0, 21.5, 27.5, 33.5, 39.5, 46.0, 51.5)
cases = c(0,1,3,8,9,8,10,5)
miners = c(98,54,43,48,51,38,28,11)
successes = cases
failures = miners - cases

# Full model (FM)
m = glm(cbind(successes, failures) ~ exposure, family=binomial(link='logit'))
# Reduced model (RM)
m0 = glm(cbind(successes, failures) ~ 1, family=binomial(link='logit'))

# Likelihoods
ln_L_FM = logLik(m)[1]
ln_L_RM = logLik(m0)[1]
LR = 2*(ln_L_FM - ln_L_RM)
print(LR)
```

Now, to calculate the logLikelihood of the full model:

$$
\ln[L(FM)] = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \ln(\hat{\pi}_i) + \sum_{i=1}^n (n_i -y_i)\ln(1-\hat{\pi}_i)
$$

```
y = cases/miners
n = miners
p = fitted(m)

t1 = y*log(p)
t1[1] = 0
t1 = sum(t1)

t2 = (n-y)* log(1-p)
t2 = sum(t2)

loglikFM = t1 + t2
```

However, this gives `-52.70837` whereas logLik(m) gives -14.43861. What am I doing wrong? How can I get `logLik(m)` by hand? How can I get logLik(m0) by hand? I can't seem to get the same numbers for either of them.